# Wagtail endless pagination using Django EL(Endless) Pagination

Tags: wagtail, django-endless-pagination

I need to implement AJAX based endless pagination in Wagtail. I have gone crazy in order to make it work.

Do I have to use the serve method in order to pass new results on scroll?

Or do I create a view url and js call.

Hopefully that is not too vague but my code is already messed up...